# Find maximum value and the hour for each day (python , pandas)

Tags: python, max, pandas-groupby, return-value

I am using python and pandas.

I did `groupby` by day of the week and by hour. What I want is to find the maximum daily value for each parameter, and what time it was for every day. My problem is that I lose the hour if I take use `max()`

How can I find the maximum value and time each day?

My code is:

```
grouped_df=df.groupby(["day_of_week","hour"]) 
                      ["parameter1","parameter2","parameter3","parameter4","parameter5"].mean()

grouped_df.parameter2.max()

> 1402
```

This code gives me just the value, but no day and no hour.

Link to the picture of the df here [This is the grouped_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67RAv.png)

Comment: Show us your dataframe

Comment: There is a link at the end of the question with a picture